# What Windows/MacOS software to use for analyzing TCP/UDP connections from applications on Iphone, Ipad?

Tags: windows, osx, software-testing, iphone-app, network-monitor

The application is installed on the iPhone, iPad. It sends both HTTP/HTTPS requests and TCP/UDP requests.
Wi-Fi point configured on a Windows laptop. Iphone/Ipad connected to the Internet through this point.

1. **Wireshark** shows only the hosts to which the request from the application goes. But the message body is encrypted and therefore cannot be viewed. Wireshark does not provide a MITM certificate.
2. **Burp Suite** allows to install a certificate on iPhone/iPad and pass all traffic through Burp. But it only shows HTTP/HTTPS requests. But I also need to catch TCP/UDP requests and view their body.
3. **Charles proxy** allows you to install your certificate, just like Burp, but just like Burp, it only catches HTTP/HTTPS connections. It also shows forwarded socket:// requests, but doesn't show their body.

Please recommend any Windows (more preferred option) or MacOS software that shows TCP/UDP connections with the decrypted body of these requests?